# Custom command to insert figures side by side

Tags: floats, subfloats, expl3

I need to write a code in expl3. it needs to create a command that:

- insert figures side by side on the page
- if the number is odd, insert the caption next to the last image
- Figures should not exceed the bottom of the page.
  how to check if there is space on the page, if there is not use the \clearpage command?

  ```
  \documentclass{report}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \keys_define:nn { addfigs }
  {
    figures .clist_set:N = \l_addfigs_figures_seq,    
    subcaptions .clist_set:N = \l_addfigs_captions_seq,    
    sublabels .clist_set:N = \l_addfigs_labels_seq,    
    caption .tl_set:N = \l_addfigs_caption_tl,    
    label .tl_set:N = \l_addfigs_label_tl,    
  }
  \NewDocumentCommand{\addfigures}{ m }    
  {
    \group_begin:    
    \keys_set:nn { addfigs } { #1 }    
    \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int    
    \begin{figure}[htb!]    
        \bool_while_do:nn    
        { \int_compare_p:n { \l_tmpa_int < \clist_count:N \l_addfigs_figures_seq } }    
        {
            \add_figure:nnn
            { \clist_item:Nn \l_addfigs_figures_seq { \l_tmpa_int + 1 } }
            { \clist_item:Nn \l_addfigs_captions_seq { \l_tmpa_int + 1 } }
            { \clist_item:Nn \l_addfigs_labels_seq { \l_tmpa_int + 1 } }
            \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
            \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \l_tmpa_int < \clist_count:N \l_addfigs_figures_seq } }
            { \hfill }
        }
        \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { \clist_count:N \l_addfigs_figures_seq } { 2 } = 1 } }
        {
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}[t][][t]{0.49\textwidth}%
                \caption{\tl_use:N \l_addfigs_caption_tl}
                \label{\tl_use:N \l_addfigs_label_tl}
            \end{minipage}%
        }
        \bool_if:nF { \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { \clist_count:N \l_addfigs_figures_seq } { 2 } = 1 } }
        {
            \caption{\tl_use:N \l_addfigs_caption_tl}
            \label{\tl_use:N \l_addfigs_label_tl}
        }
  \end{figure}
  \group_end:
  }
  \cs_new_protected:Npn \add_figure:nnn #1#2#3
  {  
    \begin{minipage}[t][][c]{0.49\textwidth}
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
            \setlength\fboxrule{0.75pt}
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax]{#1}}
            \caption{#2}
            \label{#3}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
  }
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  \begin{document}
  \addfigures{
        figures = {
        ./imagens/cx-01.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-02.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-03.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-04.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-05.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-06.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-07.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-08.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-09.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-10.jpg,%
        ./imagens/cx-11.jpg},
    subcaptions = {Caixa 01 Caixa 02,Caixa 03,Caixa 04,Caixa 05,Caixa 06,Caixa 07,Caixa 08,Caixa 09,Caixa 10, Caixa 11},
    sublabels = {subfig:cx01, subfig:cx02, subfig:cx03, subfig:cx04, subfig:cx05, subfig:cx06, subfig:cx07, subfig:cx08, subfig:cx09, subfig:cx10, subfig:cx11},
    caption = {My main caption},
    label = {fig:mainlabel}
  }
  \end{document}
  ```